# Why does my program break when I try to refresh the usestate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

When I try to refresh the usestate my program just breaks. The problematic line is "setMesses(_messages);". I tried to capitalized the usestate but nothing has changed.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Message from './Message';
import * as firebase from "firebase";

function MessContainer() {
    let counter = 0;
    let _messages = [];
    const [messes, setMesses] = useState([{this: null}]);

    firebase.database().ref().child('counter').on('value', function(snapshot){
        counter = snapshot.child("counter").val();
    });

    function load(_counter){
        firebase.database().ref().child('messages/' + _counter).on('value', function(snapshot){        
            let _chet = {}; 
            let _name = snapshot.child("name").val();

            _chet.mess =  _name + ": " + snapshot.child("message").val();

            if(_name === document.getElementById("name").value){
              _chet.status = "right";
            } else {
              _chet.status = "left";
            }
            _messages.push(_chet);
        });
    }


    function loadChet(){
        _messages = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < counter; i++){
            load(i);
        }
        console.log(_messages);
        setMesses(_messages);
        setTimeout(loadChet, 1000); 
    }

    loadChet();

    return (
        <div>{messes.map(_mess => (
            <Message mess={_mess.mess} status={_mess.status} />
        ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default MessContainer;
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: "Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop." After a few second the whole site collapses. And I cant see more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this happens is because you call `loadChet` and this calls `setMesses` wich makes the component rerender and call `loadChet` again, causing a infinity loop.

You shouldn't call `loadChet` on the function, maybe use `useEffect` and call it only once will. When do you need to call `loadChet` ?

## Edit:

Try this

```
function MessContainer() {
    let counter = 0;
    let _messages = [];
    const [messes, setMesses] = useState([{this: null}]);

    firebase.database().ref().child('counter').on('value', function(snapshot){
        counter = snapshot.child("counter").val();
    });

    function load(_counter){
        firebase.database().ref().child('messages/' + _counter).on('value', function(snapshot){        
            let _chet = {}; 
            let _name = snapshot.child("name").val();

            _chet.mess =  _name + ": " + snapshot.child("message").val();

            if(_name === document.getElementById("name").value){
              _chet.status = "right";
            } else {
              _chet.status = "left";
            }
            _messages.push(_chet);
        });
    }


    function loadChet(){
        _messages = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < counter; i++){
            load(i);
        }
        console.log(_messages);
        setMesses(_messages);
        setTimeout(loadChet, 1000); 
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        loadChet();
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>{messes.map(_mess => (
            <Message mess={_mess.mess} status={_mess.status} />
        ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: How should i fix it, to re-render the data from firebase?

Comment: In every two, or three second.

Comment: I don't know what useEffetc is :((

Comment: @BudaÖrs Every two or three seconds or when the data in the firebase changes? Take a look at the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: When the data changes... But I don't know how to measure the change so i just refresh it.

Comment: @BudaÖrs Try putting `loadChet` inside `useEffect`. Also don't forget to `import {useEffect} from 'react'`

Comment: @BudaÖrs reading the docs, medium articles, videos on youtube, and practicing. The same way you learn React ;)

Comment: Thank you for you patient, and helping!! I'm so happy :)))